# Is it possible to have two footer in one page in Excel?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have two footer in one page in Excel?

I'm trying to create a template.

My template must includes 2 footer. 
But I don't know if it is possible 
to create two footer in one page. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I feel that this should be moved to superuser instead of stackoverflow

Comment: Why two footers? What is your data for the footers? Why can it not be organised to live in the existing footer areas. Excel footers have a left, middle and right panel. In each panel you can put content. In each panel you can place line breaks. Please explain the architecture of your desired two-level footer and why it does not fit in the Excel out-of-the-box footer functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has three footers - left, center and right.   Each footer can also have multiple lines.

Here's an example to set the contents in VBA :

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "left"
        .CenterFooter = "centre"
        .RightFooter = "right"
End With
```